# Why is the YouTube video content not populating?

Tags: jquery, flash, youtube-api

I am trying to get a youtube video to play in a fancybox popup window. The popup window comes up okay, but the video does not play. Firebug indicates that all the necessary elements are loading, but no video.

On [this page](http://www.theideapeople.com/projectpath/ideapeople-new/inside1.html) everything works fine.

On [this page](http://www.theideapeople.com/projectpath/ideapeople-new/index.html) the window pops up but no video.

Here is the html:

```
<div id="play-btn">
   <a class="play-video" href="#flashArea1">Play Video</a>
</div>
<div style="display:none">
<div id="flashArea1" class="flashArea1" style="height:376;"><p>This content requires the Adobe Flash Player.<br /><a href="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer">
<img src="http://www.adobe.com/images/shared/download_buttons/get_flash_player.gif" alt="Get Adobe Flash player" /><br />Get Flash</a></p>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
var mainswf = new SWFObject("youtube_player_standalone.swf", "main", "600", "250", "9", "#000000");
mainswf.addParam("scale", "noscale");
mainswf.addParam("wmode", "window");
mainswf.addParam("allowFullScreen", "true");
mainswf.addVariable("youtube_id", "_EC2tmFVNNE");
mainswf.addVariable("title", "Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows");
mainswf.addVariable("controls_always_on", "false");
mainswf.addVariable("controls_fade_out_time", "5");
mainswf.addVariable("volume_cookie_on", "true");
mainswf.write("flashArea1");
</script>
</div><!-- end flash -->
```

Here is the jQuery that pops up the box:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$("a.play-video").fancybox({
'hideOnContentClick': false
});
});
</script>
```

I would appreciate any assistance. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try validating your page also for some reason you have php code showing up in your source I would fix that stuff first then maybe your youtube will show

you have two instances of the same swf code in your html try pitching one of them

ie

```
<div style="display:none">
<div id="flashArea3" class="flashArea3" style="height:376;"><p>This content requires the Adobe Flash Player.<br /><a href="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer">
                        <img src="http://www.adobe.com/images/shared/download_buttons/get_flash_player.gif" alt="Get Adobe Flash player" /><br />Get Flash</a></p>

    </div>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    var mainswf = new SWFObject("youtube_player_standalone.swf", "main", "600", "250", "9", "#000000");
    mainswf.addParam("scale", "noscale");
    mainswf.addParam("wmode", "window");
    mainswf.addParam("allowFullScreen", "true");
    mainswf.addVariable("youtube_id", "_EC2tmFVNNE");
    mainswf.addVariable("title", "Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows");
    mainswf.addVariable("controls_always_on", "false");
    mainswf.addVariable("controls_fade_out_time", "5");
    mainswf.addVariable("volume_cookie_on", "true");
    mainswf.write("flashArea3");
  </script>
```

Comment: I disabled the php - that is for bringing in Wordpress blog feeds. The page validates, but still no video.

Comment: Right now they all reference the same file player swf file, but all instances have unique IDs.

Comment: yes but the variable names and all the code are the same.. just try it and see if it fixes the problem ?

Comment: I removed it and the problem persists. I appreciate your efforts.

Comment: hmm ok well you are loading a flash item in there but your getting an error loading http://www.theideapeople.com/projectpath/ideapeople-new/youtube_player_standalone.swf

Comment: That is the default player. The parameters are determined by the settings in the page.

Comment: out of curiosity when you took out the extras did you take out all the extras or just one ?